# type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis in eslint in vue+ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I have a simple function in my methods and I couldn't find any doc about this `eslint` error and I don't know why I get this `eslint` error

```js
// logic.ts

import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
 ...

 methods: {
  selectTab (tabIndex:number) {
   console.log(tabIndex)
  },
 },
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have `lang="ts"` in `<script>` if it is a .vue file. Can you also give a bit more information

Comment: I write my codes in `logic.ts` and use it in `*.vue` as a mixin and in my `*.vue` files, yes I have `lang="ts"` @ZloiGoroh